# Efficient storage and retrieval of 2-dimensional data in database from JVM

Tags: database, performance, 2d

I need to store 2 dimensional data, that is points (x,y) in a database. What I mean by database is that the data needs to have some persistence to disk, its ok if it flushes now and then.

Most of my queries are going to be to find the points within a rectangle. So this would be a query to find all Point's where ( Xa < Point < Xb AND Ya < Point < Yb).

It would be best if the database is within the JVM rather than having to call out to a server database.

Also it would be good if it does efficient caching.

Need to store data on disk at some point, the data needs to persist after my software has exited.

Need to query LARGE data, terabytes of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use PostgresSQL with the postgres geospatial, if I need a lot of speed I will keep all of it on a ram disk in memory and synchronizing to a real disk via master/slave.

I will communicate with PostgresSQL with JDBC (not Hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some in-memory database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [Java DB](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Database/javadb_10_5/index.html).